Creation of objects in c++
Consider we have a class Foo where we have a default and copy constructor what is the difference between creating object like Foo f1 and Foo f1 = Foo() , in my test both of them call the default constructor , does they reserved in different memory location as the one created with pointer

No, see The Nightmare of Initialization in C++ video and C++ initialization meme, not to mention c++17 and c++20 added a few more initialization schemes so those sources are outdated

Foo f1; is default initialization. Foo f1 = Foo(); value initialize a temporary object and then copy initialize f1 . In reality the compiler will likely generate the same default initialization code for both cases.

Foo f1 = Foo() is Copy-initialization - "...since C++17 - if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see copy elision...."

they have been equivalent in all compilers since C++98 , what's new in C++17 is that compiler MUST make them equivalent to be called a C++17 compiler, it is now a rule.

@AhmedAEK Pre-C++17 compilers had to reject the second one if the class is non-movable, and now they're not allowed to reject that.

Foo f1 default-constructs f1.  Foo f1 = Foo() is a little more complicated, since its meaning has evolved and depends on version of the C++ standard: semantically, before C++17, it default-constructs a temporary Foo and constructs f1 using that temporary (via copy or move constructor), but an implementation was permitted but not required to elide (i.e. not create) the temporary (but a diagnostic is still required if the copy/move constructor is inaccessible). Since C++17, Foo f1 = Foo() is copy initialisation, and copy elision is mandatory.

@HolyBlackCat   To add ...  before C++11 (i.e. before move semantics) compilers had to reject if the class was non-copyable.   Even if the temporary was elided (which was not mandatory).

Dupe: For a class, what is the difference between default-initialization, and copy-initialization to a value-initialized prvalue?

@user12002570 Both dupes are outdated and don't mention C++17 mandatory copy elision. They also don't explain zero-initialization vs default-initialization. Once again I suggest that we should ensure the dupes have correct answers before using them as dupes.

@HolyBlackCat Add the answer in the dupe target, deleting it from here. This is what is suggested by mods to me when I used to answer dupes 2 years back.

@user12002570 My point is that it should be your job as a person closing the question to ensure the dupe has a correct answer on it. :/

@HolyBlackCat And my point was that if there are no correct answers in the dupe, then the new answer should be posted directly there in addition to the incorrect/incomplete/wrong answer to be downvoted in the dupe. Having a single canonical post will also be a good result instead of having different posts answering the same question.

Before C++17, in Foo f1 = Foo(); the compiler was allowed to create a temporary Foo instance, then move it into f1 (look up "move semantics").
Since C++17, the compiler isn't allowed to create a temporary ("mandatory copy elision"), so the two are almost completely equivalent.
The difference is that for some types, Foo f1; will leave the object uninitialized, while Foo f1 = Foo(); will zero it (just like Foo f1{}; or Foo f1 = Foo{};). This applies to all non-class types, and to those classes that either don't have a custom ("user-declared") default constructor, or have it marked =default inside of the class body; for those classes the fields that would otherwise remain uninitialized are zeroed.

does they reserved in different memory location

No, f1 ends up in the same location regardless.

as the one created with pointer

No, there are no pointers there.
